# Convert MySQL Month/Year to Datetime or Unixtime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL column in the following format, but how can I convert it to datetime or unixtime format.

**Existing format**

```
February 2015
```

**Required format**

```
2015-02-01 00:00:00
```

Any idea how this can be done using MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for this

```
 mysql> select date_format(str_to_date('February 2015','%M %Y'),'%Y-%m-01 %H:%i:%s') as date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2015-02-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```